# Logarithmic question(find $x$ in terms of $y$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I need help with the following problem:

$2\ln(x)-\ln(x+2) = \ln(y)$

I need to get $x$ in terms of $y$. Here what how far I got:

$ y = \frac{x^2}{x+2} $

How do I rearrange to get $x$ in terms of $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange and solve the quadratic $x^2 - yx - 2y = 0$ for $x$ using the quadratic formula. One of the roots may be rejected if you need positive $x$ and positive $y$ (to ensure you remain in the real domain with your original logarithmic equation).

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!

Comment: @ShootingStars: If this answer helped you, you should click on the checkmark button just to the top left of this answer below the vote buttons. This marks to the website that your problem got solved.